# AWS EMR - Hive creating new table in S3 results in AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce

I have a Hive script I'm running in EMR that is creating a partitioned Parquet table in S3 from a ~40GB gzipped CSV file also stored in S3.

The script runs fine for about 4 hours but reaches a point (pretty sure when it is just about done creating the Parquet table) where it errors out. The logs show that the error is:

```
HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
```

caused by:

```
AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request
```

There really isn't any more useful information in the logs that I can see. It is reading the CSV file fine from S3 and it creates a couple metadata files in S3 fine as well, so I've confirmed the instance has read/write permissions to the Bucket.

I really can't think of anything else that's going on and I wish there was more info in the logs about what "Bad Request" to S3 that Hive is making. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

BadRequest is a fairly meaningless response from AWS which it sends if there is any reason why it doesn't like the caller. Nobody really knows what's happening.

1. The troubleshooting docs for the ASF [S3A connector](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md) list some causes, but they aren't complete, and based on guesswork from what made the message go away.
2. If you have the request ID which failed, you can submit a support request for amazon to see what they saw on their side.

If it makes you feel any better, I'm seeing it when I try to list exactly one directory in an object store, and I'm co-author of the s3a connector. Like I said "guesswork". Once you find out, add a comment here or, if it's not in the troubleshooting doc, submit a patch to hadoop on the topic.